# cannot implicitly convert System.LINQ an explicit conversion exists are you missing a cast

Tags: javascript, api, model-view-controller, typeahead.js

I am currently trying to implement TypeAhead plugin with an API search query. The below code is a snippit I recieved from a udemy class Mosh (https://github.com/mosh-hamedani/vidly-mvc-5/blob/master/Vidly/Controllers/Api/CustomersController.cs). Upon implementing the below code I am receiving the error of

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Linq.Iqueryable' to 
>   System.Data.Entity.DbSet'. An Explicit conversion exists
>   (are you missing a cast)?

This happens on this line of code

```
vmrsQuery = vmrsQuery.Where(c => c.Description.Contains(query));
```

Does anyone else have a workaround to get this to function correctly?

```
public IHttpActionResult GetVMRS(string query = null)
    {

        var vmrsQuery = _context.VMRS;

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query))
            vmrsQuery = vmrsQuery.ToList().Where(c => c.Description.Contains(query));

        var vmrsDtos = vmrsQuery
            .ToList()
            .Select(Mapper.Map<VMRS, VMRSDto>);

        return Ok(vmrsDtos);
    }
```

Comment: Post the entire text of the error, and tell us which line of code is causing it.

Comment: Just made changes

Comment: Yep.  Now read the error message.  Are you missing a cast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't call `ToList()` on your context directly. This will pull every row from the database into memory before executing the where clause.

`vmrsQuery = vmrsQuery.ToList().Where(c => c.Description.Contains(query));`

should be

`vmrsQuery = vmrsQuery.Where(c => c.Description.Contains(query));`

Also, you probably need to explicitly define your variable.

`var vmrsQuery = _context.VMRS;`

should be

`IQueryable<VMRS> vmrsQuery = _context.VMRS;`

This is because the context could be a DbSet if using Entity Framework.

You could also just put `_context.VMRS.AsQueryable()`

Comment: IQueryable<VMRS> vmrsQuery = _context.VMRS; is what fixed it. Thank you Very Much!!!